# Make new file and replace old one using Applescript

Tags: file, applescript

So I have script that creates a file in my Documents folder with a specific name. I want to later run the code more then once so I need to replace the old file. I tried to add a replace:true in the properties but it thinks replace is a variable.

```
tell application "Finder" to make file at (path to home folder) ¬
with properties {name:"textfile.txt",replace:true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to (try to) delete the file explicitly

```
set fileName to "textfile.txt"
tell application "Finder"
    try
        delete file fileName of home
    end try
    make file at home with properties {name:fileName}
end tell
```